# Is it possible to use regular expression for Jetty's servlet-mapping?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have this one mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but i also want 
/service/master
to map to master servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>master</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/service/master</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I believe there is a conflict here since calling /service/* will trigger service servlet right away. Is there a way for me to use some kind of exclusion in servlet-mapping or may be regexp to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Servlet mappings always use the most specific match, so the path `<context>/service/master` will always map to `master`.

This is the 1st rule of mappings from the [Servlet 3.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315):

> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request
>      to the path of the servlet. A
>      successful match selects the servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This
>      is done by stepping down the path tree
>      a directory at a time, using the ’/’
>      character as a path separator. The
>      longest match determines the servlet
>      selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g.
>      .jsp), the servlet container will try
>      to match a servlet that handles
>      requests for the extension. An
>      extension is defined as the part of
>      the last segment after the last ’.’
>      character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the
>      container will attempt to serve
>      content appropriate for the resource
>      requested. If a "default" servlet is
>      defined for the application, it will
>      be used. Many containers provide an
>      implicit default servlet for serving
>      content.

Comment: so you are saying that the mapping that i have is correct? well, I have tried it and /service/master does not map to master servlet

Comment: Try another container, e.g. Tomcat. I've seen more than often oddities like that with Jetty.

Comment: As a workaround, try to have the master mapping first (haven't tested it, but I assume there's a chance this could work).

Comment: @denniss - 1) what version of Jetty are you using? 2) what version is your web.xml? Prior to Servlet 2.5 the rules for request mapping were polite suggestions, so perhaps Jetty doesn't conform. Also, note that mappings are case sensitive, so `/service/master` should match _master_ while `/service/MASTER` should match _service_.

Comment: I just did a quick test on Jetty 6.1.15 and it works fine. Note though that McDowell's comment about case sensitivity applies, and you don't have a wild card on master, so it matches `service/master` but not `service/master/x`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Google Guice.
com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.serveRegex(String regex, String... regexes)
will let you use regex in mapping.

see here http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule